# node superagent, how to detect network error when downloading binary?

Tags: node.js, superagent

my code is like this:

```
superagent.get(xxx).pipe(fs.createWriteStream("xxx"))
```

The problem is it returns right way, so I can't to `away/try-catch` or `.catch` on this to detect exception.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually listen for errors on the stream:

```
const stream = superagent.get(xxx)
stream.on('error', err => {
  console.error('Error: ', err)
})
stream.on('end', () => {
  console.log('Finished writing data');
})
stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream("xxx"))
```